# Summarise/ descriptive statistics for categorical data

Tags: stata, categorical-data

I have a dataset in Stata and would like to create a descriptive statistics table. The current problem I have is that my variables are both numerical and categorical. For the numerical variables, I know I can create a table easily with the mean, standard deviation and so on. I have just had a problem with categorical variables. For example, education encompasses 5 levels of different education and I would like to show the proportion of observations for each option within the education variable.This is just part of it. I wanted to create an overall table that has descriptive statistics for other variables, like gender, age, income, level of education and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the user-contributed command `table1` for this purpose. Type `ssc install table1` to access the package.

```
sysuse auto

table1, vars(price contn \ rep78 cat)

  +------------------------------------------------+
  | Factor               Level   Value             |
  |------------------------------------------------|
  | N                            74                |
  |------------------------------------------------|
  | Price, mean (SD)             6,165.3 (2,949.5) |
  |------------------------------------------------|
  | Repair record 1978   1       2 (3%)            |
  |                      2       8 (12%)           |
  |                      3       30 (43%)          |
  |                      4       18 (26%)          |
  |                      5       11 (16%)          |
  +------------------------------------------------+
```

Type `help table1` for additional options.

Comment: I have installed the package but I am wondering if this will allow me to create an overall table for descriptive statics for a few of my variables. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. What do you mean when you say "overall table"? Have you tried using `table1` with your desired variables?